# Javascript for flash menu not loading in IE9 but fine in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-9

I have a flash menu on a site. The menu works fine in all browsers EXCEPT IE9.  It looks like this javascript file is not loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ActiveContentDropDownWide.js"></script>
```

In IE9 it just displays BUTTON1, BUTTON2 etc but in all other browsers it displays the complete menu.  This is what happens when the ActiveContentDropDownWide.js script is removed which is why it seems to be a problem with that script and IE9.  But I could be wrong?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript file that powers some of the menu needed to be updated with a new version that supports IE9.  Once I updated it, the menu worked fine in IE9.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Fiddler capture with IE9 and FF. Then, compare the 2 captures using Fiddler's Diff feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is seems to me that the menu is hiding behind the content 
maybe it is z-index problem if the flash menu inside a div ,give it high z-index number or google for ie9 z-index problem.